# WP function not receiving Ajax variable

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm getting trying to learn some AJAX for WordPress yet getting stumped at what seems like it should be simple. AJAX function gets the ID correctly, sends it via admin-ajax.php (which I can see in XHR tab of devtools) but function won't receive it. What am I missing please?

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

    var post_id = $('article').attr('ID');
    post_id = post_id.replace('post-','');
    console.log(post_id);

    $.ajax({
        url: updatecount.ajax_url,
        data : {
            action : 'updateCount',
            post_id : post_id,
        },

        success : function( data ) {
           console.log(data)
        },

        error : function( data ) {
            console.log('failed');
        }

    })
})
```

...and the function it is calling is as follows:

```
function updateCount() {

    $post_id = intval($_POST['post_id']);
    echo 'Function has ID as: '. $post_id;
    die(); 
}
```

This returns the following console output:

```
AJAX has ID as: 187963
Function has ID as: 0
```

Comment: maybe it is a [reserved term](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms). It is not listed, but `post_id` sounds like a old wp fallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `jQuery.ajax` makes `GET` requests, but you're checking for data in `$_POST`. You'll either want to check `$_GET` on the PHP side, or add `method: 'POST'` to your `jQuery.ajax` options object.

Note that if you're using a very old jQuery (pre 1.9.0) you'll need to use `type: 'POST'` instead of `method: 'POST'`, per the [docs on the options object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings).

Comment: Thanks Joel that was the issue, using `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`. All working as expected now, nice one.